# Get data from HTML DOM to microsoft word

Tags: html, vba, dom, ms-word

I have been trying to get data from google patent to Microsoft word
I am using following VBA to extract the information

```
 Function Get_URL_Data(StrUrl As String) As String
'References to Internet Explorer & Microsoft HTML required
Dim Browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim StrTmp As String, StrTxt As String
Set Browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
'Open the web page
Browser.navigate StrUrl
Do While Browser.Busy
  DoEvents
Loop
Set HTMLDoc = Browser.Document
Do While Browser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to google.com"
  DoEvents
Loop
'Get the data
On Error Resume Next
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("claim-text")(1)
Get_URL_Data = StrTmp
'Close the browser
Browser.Quit
Set HTMLDoc = Nothing: Set Browser = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

My html contains li class="claim"

```
    <li class="claim"> <div id="c-en-0001" num="0001" class="claim">
    <div class="claim-text">A process for producing a compound represented by formula (II):
<chemistry id="chem0047" num="0047"> <div class="patent-image"> <a href="//patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/EP1925611A1/imgb0047.png"> <img id="ib0047" file="imgb0047.tif" wi="40" he="40" img-content="chem" img-format="tif" src="//patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/EP1925611A1/imgb0047.png" class="patent-full-image" width="160" height="160" alt="Figure imgb0047"> </a> </div> <attachments> <attachment idref="chem0047" attachment-type="cdx" file="CDX"> </attachment> <attachment idref="chem0047" attachment-type="mol" file="MOL"> </attachment> </attachments> </chemistry>
(wherein Y represents -COR, wherein R represents a C1-C8 alkoxy group, a C6-C14 aryloxy group, a C2-C8 alkenyloxy group, a C7-C26 aralkyloxy group, or a di(C1-C6 alkyl)amino group; and R<sup>1</sup> represents a C2-C7 alkoxycarbonyl group), which comprises treating a compound represented by formula (I):
<chemistry id="chem0048" num="0048"> <div class="patent-image"> <a href="//patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/EP1925611A1/imgb0048.png"> <img id="ib0048" file="imgb0048.tif" wi="26" he="34" img-content="chem" img-format="tif" src="//patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/EP1925611A1/imgb0048.png" class="patent-full-image" width="104" height="136" alt="Figure imgb0048"> </a> </div> <attachments> <attachment idref="chem0048" attachment-type="cdx" file="CDX"> </attachment> <attachment idref="chem0048" attachment-type="mol" file="MOL"> </attachment> </attachments> </chemistry>
(wherein Y has the same meaning as defined above) in a solvent with aqueous ammonia or a solution of ammonia in C1-C4 alcohol and, subsequently, with a di(C1-C6 alkyl) dicarbonate.</div>
  </div>
```

I tried to figure out how to scrap  but i could not figure out what li class and how to scrap using HTML DOM

I tried working around by trying different of following but i am not able to get the results.
I tried to scrap

```
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("claim-text")
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.getElementById("claim-text")
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("claim-text")
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.document.getElementsByTagName("claim-text")
```

also tried scrapping

```
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("claim")
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.getElementById("claim")
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("claim")
StrTmp = HTMLDoc.document.getElementsByTagName("claim")
```

I did not get any results yet.
Am I on right track?

Comment: I don't really understand the question...

Comment: I want to extract data from the html show aboe to microsoft word document

Comment: I asume you're having a problem when you're trying to extract the data, what is exactly the problem?

Comment: Well, does the function return what you expect? If yes, then you're on the right track, as far as it goes. If you're asking "Where do I go from here" then you need to ask that, but in a more specific manner. You need to state specifically where you're blocked and can't get any further.

Comment: @ithil: I did not get anything so far as I am new to vba and HTML DOM. I wanted to know how to scrap data that has <li class="claim"> type of class or <div class="claim-text">

Comment: @cindy: It Doesn't Return what I expect.